# Making a Bezier curve based on 3 points the line will intersect

Tags: trigonometry, bezier

A quadratic bezier curve needs [these](http://prntscr.com/njq5ds) three points, but I do not have an ordered pair of p1. Instead, I have the ordered pair of points [here](http://prntscr.com/njq77l)

The middle point (P1) is the highest point of the parabola.

The parabola is equal in both sides

How do I get the 3 points from image 1 using the points from image 2?

Comment: what do you mean by "get the 3 points...using the points from image 2"? A Bezier curve is defined by the points, Points in one curve does not define points in other curve. If you change the points, you get a different Bezier curve.

Comment: If there is still any confusion, I have the ordered pair of the two ends and the peak of the parabola. For a quadratic bezier curve, you need the point where both starting angles intersect. So I need to convert  the position of the peak of the parabola to the position where the two angles intersect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the knowledge explained in https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#abc and you should be good to go. You'll need to decide which time value that "somewhere on the curve" point has, and then you can use the formula for the projection ratio to find the actual control point coordinate.

However, at `t=0.5` the ratio is just "1:1" so things get even easier because your point projects onto the midpoint of the line that connects that first and last point, and the real control point is the same distance "above" your point as the point is above that line:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OViCo.png]

So you just compute the midpoint:

```
m = 
  x: (p1.x + p2.x) / 2
  y: (p1.y + p2.y) / 2
```

and the x and y distance to the midpoint from the "p2 you have" point:

```
d =
  x: (p2.x - m.x)
  y: (p2.y - m.y)
```

and then the real `p2` is simply that distance away from the "p2 you have":

```
real2 = 
  x: p2.x + d.x
  y: p2.y + d.y
```

However, note that this **only** works for t=0.5: both that projected point on the `start--end` line and the distance ratios will be (possibly very) different for any other `t` value and you should use the formula that the Bezier primer talks about.

Also note that what you call "the peak" is in no way guaranteed to be at t=0.5... for example, have a look at this curve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmvRo.png]

The point that is marked as belonging to t=0.5 is certainly not where you would say the "peak" of the curve is (in fact, that's closer to t=0.56), so if all you have is three points, you technically *always* have incomplete information and you're going to have to invent some rule for deciding how to fill in the missing bits. In this case "what t value do I consider my somewhere-on-the-curve point to be?".